# Why can't I select these extruded lines?

Tags: modeling

I have no idea what to do,these lines are totally unselectable.
They appeared when I was trying to extrude an object but I did it too far.

I can't delete them and I fear I may have ruined everything!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Upload blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's up on the thingy.

Comment: You will need to give us a link to it :)

Comment: Ooh Yes! :3 ...
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4228" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4228/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to *Vertex Selection* mode, turn off *Limit Selection to Visible* option in the 3D view header, border select your vertex and delete them.

[image]